# How can I change MySQL DB UTC times for a Laravel project?

Tags: mysql, laravel, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

I have a Laravel project with a MySQL DB set to the UTC time zone. I want to be able to change the UTC time zone times in the DB to various time zones depending on where the client accessing the data is.

I can set the `timezone` parameter in the `config/app.php` dynamically based on the client, but that doesn't seem to affect the times going into the DB when I use the `save` method on a Laravel method (basically, everything goes back to UTC).

There are probably a number of ways to implement this, but after searching around quite a bit, I cannot find a way to get the DB times in UTC to switch over to my time zone of choice.

It's worth noting that my project sometimes uses Laravel models for queries and sometimes uses the query builder from the `DB` class. I'm not sure if they need to be handled differently, but all the same, I'm looking for a solution that handles both use cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_timezone

```
$data->setTimezone(Auth::user()->timezone)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Charles, but I ended up going a different route (mostly because I realized that I didn't properly understand the problem when I asked the question). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Charles, I appreciate your answer, but I ended up realizing that the dates were going into the DB correctly, but when I was comparing them to the MySQL `NOW()` function, the `NOW()` part was what I needed to convert.

As such, I ended up using the `CONVERT_TZ` function as follows to get what I wanted:

```
CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'US/Eastern')
```

The third parameter was made variable, but you get the point. Also, this feels like a bit of a hack, but it works for now.